# Why does HTML insert automatic line breaks before and after a line?

Tags: html

I have the following html code. When I see the output I see that a line break has been inserted before and after the text.

But no line break is inserted when the doctype is changed to

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

I do not want the line breaks. What can I do without changing the doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="220">
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom" align="left">
      <p>Test Message</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you sure you're seeing a line break and not the default padding on a p element?

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data. It seems it's not the case. And please use CSS instead of those margin attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I think this will be a solution.

Set the padding and margin of the P element in your css to 0.

Here's an example

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Only `margin` needs to be set to zero, since the “line breaks” (empty space) are caused by default top and bottom margin of `p` elements. Setting `padding` to zero causes no harm, though.

Answer (score 0):

this is enough to solve your problem

```
p{
   margin:0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/q5VNC/)